# PHP How to adjust availability timezones

Tags: php, timezone

When a user signs up for my site they enter their weekly availability in this format:

Monday 1300 to 1400
Monday 2100 to 2200

Tuesday 1200 to 1300
Tuesday 1400 to 1500

Etc.

They also indicate their timezone based on a select menu, such as America/Los_Angeles.

What I want to happen is for those times to be adjusted based on the timezones of users that visit their profiles who have different timezones set. What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up doing this:

```
<?php while ($ava = mysql_fetch_array($avail_action)) { 
    date_default_timezone_set($profile_owners_timezone);
    $timestamp_from = strtotime($ava['time_from']);
    $timestamp_to = strtotime($ava['time_to']);

            date_default_timezone_set($_SESSION['timezone']);
    $time_from = date("g:i A", $timestamp_from);
    $time_to = date("g:i A", $timestamp_to); ?>
```

Basically I got the profile "owner's" timezone that he/she entered, set timezone to that, then set the timezone to "viewer's" timezone and set the variable to that.

Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Store their availability as seconds from the EPOCH, and then convert those to proper times for users based on their time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Store the difference between UTC and selected timezone in value of field

```
<option value="3">UTC+3 timezone</option>
<option value="-5">UTC-5 timezone</option>
```

then add or cut it from to the output of hours.
If such difference provide negative result or more than 24 hours - set next or previous day of the week.

I think you don't realy need unixtime for such intervals.

Comment: This is a bad idea since DST works differently for different time zones at different times. Relying on something like this is hacky at best, and possibly wrong at times.

Comment: i think you always know what to display to current user depending on his settings, because server timezone settings are known. that's another case if code must work on any server with different time zones.